# Comparing elements in Integer list in Java

Tags: java, list

I am trying to read line by line from the file, then compare numbers in that file.

I am unsure why the program is not executing past the if statement, since my first two numbers in the file are as follows:

```
1
3
6
4
```

I am expecting `increased` value to go up, but it doesn't even hit that point.

```
public static void numComparison() throws IOException, NumberFormatException {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/WorkAcc/Desktop/file.txt"));
        String lines;
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        int increased = 0;

        while ((lines = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(lines));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i<=list.size(); i++)
            if (list.get(i) < list.get(i++)){
                increased++;
            }
            else{
                continue;
            }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `list.get(i++)` does?

Comment: @ScottHunter I think it will increment the i to 1

Comment: In addition to the `i++` issue raised by Scott, your `for` loop is setup to do `list.get()` beyond the end of your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two simple changes will make your code work properly.

- First of all, `i++` won't be working in this case. The `i++` actually changes (increments) the value of `i`. Use `i+1` instead to get a new number without altering `i`.
- You should also change the end point of your for loop, or you will always get the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

This will work:

```
public static void numComparison() throws IOException, NumberFormatException {

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/WorkAcc/Desktop/file.txt"));
    String lines;
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    int increased = 0;

    while ((lines = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(lines);
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(lines));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<list.size()-1; i++){  // -1 so you dont compare the last element of
                                            // your list to an element that doesnt exist
        if (list.get(i) < list.get(i+1)){
            increased++;
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }    
    System.out.println(increased);
}
```